# config php.ini for using Zend AutoDiscovery

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, autodiscovery

I make a web-service with Zend 1.12 and tested it in my local server. It works perfectly but when I uploaded a file to my host the `wsdl` page shows the wrong result.
The export:
[image: Result]

I think it's related to `PHP.ini` but I don't know exactly what the correct config to solve this problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer :)
the server need to set below command in php.ini

```
output_buffering = 4096
extension=php_soap.dll
```